# How to make subscription allow access to document?

Tags: security, inheritance, odoo-10

I'm working on access restriction to document.
For now my module let user to restrict access to partners.

I need to allow followers to access shared documents.

This is my row-level access rule.

```
<record model="ir.rule" id="partner_access_user_rule">
 <field name="name">Partners only for editors</field>
 <field name="model_id" ref="base.model_res_partner"/>
 <field name="domain_force">['|',('user_id','in', [user.id,False]),('message_follower_ids','in',[user.partner_id.id])]</field>
 <field name="groups" eval="[(4,ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
</record>
```

It is supposed to work this way: if uder_id is not defined everyone may see the document. Otherwise the document should be visible by assigned user_id and followers. Everything works, exept followers. They can't access document they subscribed to.

Answer (score 0):

mail_followers have relation to res.partners(partner_id) not to res.users.

Followers usually can't access the record. As there will be a lot of customers for a company and we can't give access to all customers as users to the record.

If you are trying to give access to the user assigned to this customer, then you can use related user to that customer. *['|',('user_id','in', [user.id,False]),('message_follower_ids.partner_id','=',user.partner_id.id)]*

Comment: There was typo in previous comment. I have tried this domain filters: <field name="domain_force">('message_follower_ids','=',user.partner_id.user_id.id)</field> and now I have error "invalid leaf" as mentioned before. When I try this: ['|',('user_id','in', [user.id,False]),'message_follower_ids','in',[user.partner_id.user_id.id])] it results ProgrammingError: Operator is not exist: integer = boolean
LINE 1: SELECT "res_id" FROM "mail_followers" WHERE "id" IN (false)

Comment: Invalid leaf error is shown when we use wrong format. format for domain force is <field name="domain_force">[('field_name','=','some_value')]</fie‌​ld>

Comment: Suggested rule doesn't not work, current user still can't access partners he supscribed for. Strange thing, my rule is based on the book "Odoo 10 developers essential" by Daniel Reis, the business logic and access rules are the same, but in my app subscription didn't allow access. https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Odoo-10-Development-Essentials/blob/master/Chapter%2003/security/todo_access_rules.xml

Comment: From your domain ('message_follower_ids','in',[user.partner_id.id]) itis not clear what you are trying to achieve. mail_follower_ids is a relation to 'mail.followers' and you are trying to match it with 'res.partner'. If you are trying to match mail_follower_ids's partner id with related partner of user use ('message_follower_ids.partner_id','=',user.partner_id.id)

Comment: Your later comment didn't help. I need the same functionaluty as project visibility have. For exaple: 1) partner ASUS (from odoo demo data) have no assigned user_id and is visible to all employees. 2) partner ASUS have assigned user_id (administrator) and is visible only to assigned user. 3) administaror adds user Demo to Asus' message_follower_ids (this field is not seen in technical meny - database structure - models - res.partner, but it is present in partner form view) and I need Demo user to see partners, which have assigned user_id and contain Demo user in filed message_follower_ids.

Comment: well that's strange, I've tried my domain in last comment in my local and it works fine. When I add demo user only then the field is shown, don't know what you are missing. I've updated my answer with complete domain.

Comment: Note that I have previously created rule <field name="domain_force">
[('create_uid','=',user.id)]
</field> . The rule restricts access to partners alreary assigned with somebody. Does your rule work along with it?

Comment: Now I have an idea to combine rule1 with your one, and add a rule2 for unassigned partners. rule1: ['|',('create_uid','=',user.id),('user_id','in', [user.id,False])] rule2: [('message_follower_ids.partner_id','=',user.partner_id.id)] .What does 'in' means in my rule, and why does your rule don't have it, if we need to check if current user belong to partners' message_follower_ids?

Comment: in means user_id is present in the list given(in your case [user.id,False]).